# Converting WAV to PCM

Tags: wav, conversion, pcm

I have WAV files and need to convert them to PCM (44,1k, 16bit, Mono) format. How can I do this from the DOS console?

Answer (score 4):

This calls for **ffmpeg**.

```
C:\enc>ffmpeg -acodec pcm_s16le -ar 44100 -i "input.mp3" outfile.wav

Input #0, mp3, from 'input.mp3':
  Duration: 00:03:52.75, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 255 kb/s
    Stream #0.0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 256 kb/s
Output #0, wav, to 'outfile.wav':
    Stream #0.0: Audio: pcm_s16le, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 1411 kb/s
```

Of course it also takes CCITT A-Law, CCITT u-Law and almost anything .wav as input.

To downmix to mono, use `-ac 1` (as in ***a**udio **c**hannels=1*).

Comment: i needed to go from one wav format to a PCM wav and i used the simpler command line of `ffmpeg -i "infile.wav" "outfile.wav"`. YMMV, but it worked great for me.

Answer (score 1):

There is a DOS version of SoX available on its [Links](http://sox.sourceforge.net/Main/Links) page.